# Line bundles over $\mathbb R P^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-space

[As in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600404/line-bundle-over-s2), I'm continuing studying line bundles. Now it's line bundle over $\mathbb R P^2$. I know that this bundle is not trivial. So I want list up to equivalence all bundles over $\mathbb R P^2$.

When I've studied bundles over spheres there was great approach that called clutching functions. 
But if there is some direct methods to do this (like in the link), I'd like to know them.

**EDIT**

[In this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600404/line-bundle-over-s2/600449#600449) user86418 has constructed continuation of local trivilization. Maybe we can do something similiar here?

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb RP^2$ can be covered by 3 affine charts (on each of which the bundle is trivial)

Answer (score 1):

Real line bundles are classified by their [Stiefel-Whitney classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%E2%80%93Whitney_class). Real line bundles over $X$ correspond to $H^1(X;Z_2)$. In case of $RP^2$ there seems to be only 2 line bundles: tautological and trivial.